# VSCode only creating Launch.json and Tasks.json files for one of many projects

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-code

When running the following commands to add two projects to a solution in VSCode I am having problems getting VSCode to automatically create the proper Launch.json items for both projects. I am getting the message at the top of VSCode where I can click Yes, but it only create Launch and Tasks for one of the projects, not both. How can I have VSCode add to the Launch.json and Tasks.json for the other project?

```
dotnet webapi -n MyProj.Api  
dotnet mvc --auth Individual -n MyProj.Mvc
```

Answer (score 0):

Those two commands are dotnet core commands which have nothing to do with vscode.

When prompted to create those files, vscode will only add them to the folder you opened vscode in. Try opening vscode in the other folder as well and confirm the popup in the new instance of vscode.